# Back solving a function or goal seek in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn my way around R and I need a little help. Below is a little sample of the kind of problem I am working on.

```
myFunction <- function(price1) {
  prices <- c(1:50)
  prices[1] <- price1
  recursiveA <- vector(length = 51)
  recursiveA[1] <- 100
  for (i in 1:50) {
    recursiveA[i+1] <- 30*prices[i] + recursiveA[i]
  }
  target <- recursiveA[51]
  return(target)
}
```

What I want to do is create a new function that will find the `price1` value needed to yield a `target` value. For example in this new function I would be able to set `47320` as a parameter and it would return `300`. In the first function, `myFunction`, a value of `300` returns a value of `47320`.

How can I write a function in R to do this? Is there an existing function in R? I see through my Googling and searching on this site, a lot of people recommend the `uniroot()` function or `optimize()`. I can't figure out how to use that for something other than algebraic quadratics.

If it helps, I know that in excel I can solve this easily by using the goal seek tool. You can set a desired output and it finds the needed input from the formula(s) you define.

Please let me know if anything's unclear and I will try my best to explain further.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can optimize any function by rewriting `y = f(x)` to `f(x)-y` and finding the root of that.

Comment: Even if the function uses recursive inputs? I am pretty new to a lot of this stuff so how could I rewrite the function I gave in that form.

Comment: `myFunction(x)` returns some value. You want that value to equal `target_value)`   Write `func2<-function(x) myFunction(x) - target_value`  and run `optim` on that.

Comment: Specifically, you're probably after something like this: `func2 <- function(x) abs(myFunction(x) - 42010); optimize(func2, lower=-1000, upper=1000)`. The `abs` is necessary because the function can return negative values, and the objective is to minimise (by default) the function.

Comment: Ahhhhh! There we go. Just ran through the code that you gave me @jbaums I think this will work. I will need to test it more but I think this can definitely work! Thank you very much! 

A few years out of college and I've forgotten so much basic math. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually need a recursive function here.

Here's a vectorised approach:

```
f <- function(x) tail(cumsum(c(100, 30*c(x, 2:50))), 1)
f(123)
# 42010
```

And to reverse the operation:

```
anti_f <- function(x) (x - 30*50*51/2 + 30 - 100)/30
anti_f(42010)
# 123
```

Of course, this is less helpful when you actually *do* need to recurse. My point is just that you should look for opportunities to vectorise when possible.

---

If you want to do this with `optimize`, you can do:

```
f <- function(x) abs(myFunction(x) - 42010) 
optimize(f, lower=-1000, upper=1000)

# $minimum
# [1] 123
# 
# $objective
# [1] 2.512278e-05
```

R will search [-1000, 1000] in an attempt to find a value, `x`, that minimises the absolute value of `myFunction(x) - 42010`. In this case, it finds `123`, for which `myFunction(123)` returns `42010` and so `abs(myFunction(x) - 42010)` returns `0`.

If you want to wrap this in a function, you can do:

```
unfunction <- function(x, lower, upper) {
  optimize(function(y) abs(myFunction(y) - x), lower=lower, upper=upper)
}

unfunction(42010, -1000, 1000)

# $minimum
# [1] 123
# 
# $objective
# [1] 2.512278e-05

unfunction(47320, -1000, 1000)

# $minimum
# [1] 300
# 
# $objective
# [1] 0.0002383182
```

In our function `unfunction`, `lower` and `upper` specify the space to be searched.

Comment: Ah! I know that I should try and think in vectors as much as possible when coding in R. But the example I gave above was a really simplified version of what I am trying to do. The function I want to reverse is a lot more complicated and can't be solved by means of algebraic manipulation. I was looking more for a generic way to reverse a function. 

Right now I am trying to pursue Carl Witthoft's approach. But I am struggling with syntax.

Comment: I figured that was the case, but thought it couldn't hurt to post this anyway :)

Comment: definitely, it's still helpful. but my head hurts from trying to figure out the `optim()` function