# Solve a function in R similar to Goal Seeker in Excel

Tags: r, solver

I saw already a similar question, but I can´t figure out, how to do. Maybe you can help.

[Back solving a function or goal seek in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575395/back-solving-a-function-or-goal-seek-in-r)

```
ES <- function(y, z){-y * (1-pnorm(y/z)) + z * dnorm(y/z)} # = x
ES(906.19, 707.1) #33.47587
```

What I want is to solve for y, so z and x (33.4) is known. I have seen the solve and optim function, but I am not able to get the expected result.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the down-votes. OP has asked a perfectly fine question with a clear problem statement and reproducible code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `uniroot` to find the root of `ES(y, z) - x` for `y` given values `z = 707.1` and `x = 33.4`.

```
ES <- function(y, z) -y * (1 - pnorm(y / z)) + z * dnorm(y / z)
res <- uniroot(function(x, y, z) ES(y, z) - x, c(0, 1000), z = 707.1, x = 33.4)
```

The solution for `y` is then

```
res$root
#[1] 906.9494
```

We confirm that `E(y, z) = x`

```
ES(res$root, 707.1)
#[1] 33.4
```

Comment: That´s exactly what I was searching for. Thank you! I did not expect to get an answer after the downvotes...

Comment: You're very welcome @Sven. Don't worry about the down-votes and do stick around:-)