# Use R to solve similar Excel Goal Seek problem

Tags: r

I have an existing table like below

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaUyu.png)

The table is based on the 4 criteria on the very top.

Accrual amt = beginning amount * actual yield * 1/4

net payment = principal amount * face rate * 1/4 (except for the last pmt which pay the net payment + principal amount together)

Ending amount = Beginning Amount + Accrual Amt - Net Payment

The ultimate goal is to get the ending amount equals to zero to find out a target actual yield which right now equals to 10% (in excel then we use goal seek function but I want to replicate this process in r):

[excel goal seek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pReJS.png)

I am new to coding, and based on some research I came up with the following code:

```
f <- function(x) {
  dfSum <- df[1,1]
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    dfSum = dfSum + df[i,1]*x - df[i,3]}
  dfSum
}

# solve (or optimize)...
s <- uniroot(f, lower=0, upper=1)
```

however, the result is different from what it should be.  the correct yield should be 9.88%, the code returns the result as follows:

```
root = 0.024866
f.root = 0    
iter = 1        
init.it = [Null]       
estim.prec = 0.975134
```

Could anyone point out or correct where I did wrong??

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide usable data? Please don't provide data in an image: it can't be copied, searched, and breaks screen-readers (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272). Please edit your question to include either (a) building a frame, as in `df <- data.frame(...)`, or (b) output from `dput(x)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back solving a function or goal seek in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575395/back-solving-a-function-or-goal-seek-in-r)